# Web service with multi tenant in spring: postgres vs mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I would like to create a simple project using **spring** to control the status of some customers, with different environments. So a customer can have two environments (dev and prod), and others may have one, two or three.

The basic idea is I would like to create a Web Service using spring with the following interface:
`localhost:8080/customer1/environment1/status` to extract status data from *customer1* and *environment1*.

I have two options:

1. Using **MongoDB**, with a database per customer, a collection per environment and inside the status documents. I found the following problems:

   - I found many solutions on the web, it was for previous versions of Spring (I am using Spring 5)
   - Also, I am not sure how can I implement dynamic collections (I mean, if I make a request to `localhost:8080/customer2/environment2/status`, I not only would like to change the database but also the collection dynamically)
2. Using **Postgres**, using a schema per customer, and a table per environment (all the tables will have the same structure)

   - The problem is that the table name can be different (production, development, test and so on), so I should have to implement dynamic tables name in Spring (which I am not sure if it is possible)

I have been searching a couple of days for an easy solution for this (which initially I thought it would be easy, but looks like it is not that easy)

- What do you think it would be the best and simpler solution: **MongoDB** or **Postgres**?
- Can you provide the basics steps to reproduce it, or provide a Github repository with code I could use as a reference?

*PS: There is no need to be extra safe because it will be an internal service, so it doesn't matter the location of the customer's data: can be in the same database, or in different databases*

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your database choice should depends more on which advantages or disadvantages give you one database over the other. Second, I dont believe using a database per user its a good idea, imagine what will happen when you get 5000 users, it will be a pain administrate such amount of databases or keep changing your database every time in your code. I suggest you firstly try to get a compressed database model of your requeriments in a single database and then over that, you can work and select wich database is better for you.

I hope it helps!

Comment: If I had 5000 users, I would be rich. I know that scalability is something to have in mind, but in this case, it wouldn't be more than 10 databases.
Furthermore, the data will be erased every week, so no need to backup or administration tasks